# Will 2GB ram run Yosemite smoothly

Tags: upgrade, macos, memory

cant upgrade my 2009 iMac 2009 20" with 2GB for a few months but need to upgrade to 10.9.4 to install Yosemite.

I am currently running 10.8.1 as a fresh install of Mountain Lion which runs fine, but I dont want to install Yosemite and have OS hang and beach ball on me.

Not running anything to intensive, at most; Sublime, Spotify, terminal, Firefox

Answer (score 2):

A friend of mine recently upgraded his MacBook5,1 (2009 core 2 duo) with 2GB to Mavericks. It wasn't the most pleasant thing, but it actually didn't work out too bad for him and he even thinks there was a slight performance increase (I'm assuming due to the memory compression stuff being a touch faster than swap). I'm assuming that Yosemite isn't going to be much more stressful than Mavericks, so you can probably get away with it.

That being said, 2GB is absolutely too little these days if you're going to run more than one application. You are going to get beach balls, but perhaps *slightly* less than what you did with Mountain Lion. Again, I'm assuming this because of the memory compression introduced in Mavericks works faster than swapping to disk and with that little RAM you will be swapping out (or compressing) pages.

Answer (score 1):

I had Yosemite running on my MacBook (13" mid-2010) with 2 Gb, but it is unworkably slow.  Minimal apps including email and safari along with the OS will eat 2.7 Gb.  Everything is frustratingly slow, much more so than under Mavericks, which was ok but not great.  Just now I increased the ram to 4 Gb (the most for this machine) and everything is smooth and fast.  Do not do Yosemite with 2 Gb.  Get more memory first.

Comment: your computer can actually support up to 16BG of ram (1066mhz 8GB x2 sticks notebook DDR3 memory). My 2010 MacBook Pro has a nearly identical motherboard and runs 16GB fine, as will yours (2.4 GHz Core 2 Duo CPU.)

Answer (score 0):

I have a 2008 MacBook and I am running Yosemite and it can be very slow at times although I am putting in much more intensive use into it. I am doing computer programming and constantly running more than 5 apps at once. For basic web browsing, listening to music, and using command line you should be just fine. I'm warning you that every once in a while there will be times where you computer might slow down. If you are logging in and out of users and rebooting it will be slower than normal. Otherwise you should be fine upgrading

**edit**
I also have 2 GB of RAM

Answer (score 0):

Our school had to upgrade a slew of older, Mavericks-compatible Macs to 4GB RAM last year for them to run acceptably once we upgraded. All new Macs we've purchased in recent years come with 4GB RAM minimum, anyway, if that tells you anything. The Mavericks [specifications](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP702) (there is no such info available for Yosemite) indicate a minimum of 2GB, to cover some of the older Macs, but I can't see how a usable system can run on such sparse memory - too much RAM to disk [swapping](http://osxdaily.com/2010/10/08/mac-virtual-memory-swap/).
RAM is inexpensive, too, so it's a good investment.

Answer (score -1):

Yosemite needs a minimum of 4gb to run smoothly IMO, however 8gb is better if you're a power user.